# looping over a subset of variables in R by name

Tags: r, arrays, for-loop, crosstab

Data frame `have` contains a few thousand variables. One variable is a treatment indicator called `treatgrp` which contains values of 1, 2, or 3). Five other variables are called: `g_cA`, `r_cA`, `g_ccA`, `r_ccA`, and `g_grp`. They do not appear in order.

I want to generate frequency tables comparing `treatgrp` to the five other variables of interest. I currently do so with some wallpaper syntax:

```
table(have$treatgrp, have$g_cA,   deparse.level = 2)
table(have$treatgrp, have$r_cA,   deparse.level = 2)
table(have$treatgrp, have$g_ccA,  deparse.level = 2)
table(have$treatgrp, have$r_ccA,  deparse.level = 2)
table(have$treatgrp, have$g_grp,  deparse.level = 2)
```

This does the job. But I'd like to call `table()` once and iterate over the five different variables of interest. I tried doing so this way:

```
myvars <- c("g_cA", "r_cA", "g_ccA", "r_ccA", "g_grp")

for (i in 1:length(myvars)){
  table(have$treatgrp, have[,myvars[i]],  deparse.level = 2)
}
```

This doesn't result in an error message, but it also returns no output table.

It may be obvious that I'm used to macros and arrays in SAS based on this question. But I'd like to learn at least one way to solve this problem. I have to do things that resemble this all the time, and figuring out a more elegant solution would save me a lot of time.

Comment: Can you please add some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop you need to use a print().

```
data <- data.frame("id" = c(1:12), "treatment" = c(1, 2, 3), 
                   "v1" = c("a", "b"),
                  "v2" = c("X", "Y", "Z"))
vars <- c("v1", "v2")

for (i in 1:length(vars)) {
  t <- table(data[,vars[i]], data$treatment)
  print(t)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `iris` dataset as an example, would this work using `lapply`?

```
iris$var1 <- sample(letters, 150, replace = T)
iris$var2 <- sample(letters, 150, replace = T)
iris$var3 <- sample(letters, 150, replace = T)
myvars <- c("var1", "var2", "var3")
lapply(iris[myvars], function(x) table(iris$Species, x))
# $var1
#             x
#              a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
#   setosa     1 1 0 3 2 2 0 1 2 4 2 1 1 4 3 1 4 0 3 0 4 3 3 2 0 3
#   versicolor 3 1 2 3 0 4 1 3 5 0 1 0 1 3 5 2 2 1 5 1 2 0 1 1 1 2
#   virginica  4 0 1 1 3 4 2 1 2 1 2 4 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 0 2 2 2 3 1

# $var2
#             x
#              a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
#   setosa     3 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 0 4 1 2 2 4 4 3 2 0 1 0
#   versicolor 3 0 1 1 5 3 3 3 2 2 1 2 2 4 1 4 2 3 2 0 2 1 2 1 0 0
#   virginica  0 2 1 4 3 0 0 1 1 0 4 2 3 2 1 2 0 3 2 2 2 0 2 2 5 6

# $var3
#             x
#              a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
#   setosa     4 2 4 2 0 4 0 3 3 2 0 1 2 0 0 2 1 3 2 1 1 2 2 1 5 3
#   versicolor 0 3 1 3 1 1 1 0 1 1 3 2 1 0 0 4 4 1 3 6 2 2 2 3 2 3
#   virginica  3 0 3 3 2 0 3 1 1 2 0 2 4 4 1 4 1 3 4 0 1 1 2 3 2 0
```

Or same thing using `purrr::map`:

```
library(purrr)
map(iris[myvars], function(x) table(iris$Species, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

One solutions I've thought of:

Create a smaller data frame that includes the variables of interest from `have`, and loop over the indices

```
have_mini <- have[,c("treatgrp","g_cA", "r_cA", "g_ccA", "r_ccA", "g_grp")]
```

then reference the indices of `have_mini`

```
for (i in 2:length(have_mini)){
table(have_mini[,1], have_mini[,i],  deparse.level = 2)
}
```

But I'm still debugging this: nothing seems to print even though I don't get an error. On top of that, I'm sure there's a better way that I'm unaware of.